# When did bash quit exporting SHELL?

Tags: bash, shell, debian, environment-variables

I upgraded a Debian box from stable to Jessie and I noticed that SHELL is no longer exported, so screen and similar programs start dash for subshells instead of bash.

When was this change made and why?

Comment: I do not think it is the shell that exports SHELL environment variable. I think it is exported at the level of OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long, long time ago:

> This document details the changes between this version, bash-2.05a-rc1,
>   and the previous version, bash-2.05a-beta1.
>
> 1. Changes to Bash
>
> …
>
> w.  Bash no longer auto-exports HOME, PATH, SHELL, or TERM, even though it
>       gives them default values if they don't appear in the initial environment.

I don't know what the reason is, but it makes sense: there's no reason that running a bash script should set `SHELL` for inferior processes if it was unset. Bash only exports `PWD` (because it's supposed to, for whatever good that does), `OLDPWD` (the companion of `PWD`) and `SHLVL` (which is supposed to always be set by shells).

---

The reason `SHELL` is normally set to your login shell is that it's set in the environment by the login program (`login`, `sshd`, etc.). This should still be the case in jessie. If some login method doesn't set `SHELL`, that's probably a bug in the login method.

Comment: This is fun, given that I haven't used a version of bash older than four for long enough to have quit checking version in scripts and both xdm and ssh logins started showing the change in behaviour . . . it must be pam.